# May a valid HTML custom element include two hyphens or dashes, eg. <my-custom-element>?

Tags: html, custom-element

I am reading the spec on [**Valid HTML Custom Element Names**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name):

> ```
> A valid custom element name is a sequence of characters name that
> meets all of the following requirements:
>
> name must match the PotentialCustomElementName production:
>
> PotentialCustomElementName ::=
>     [a-z] (PCENChar)* '-' (PCENChar)*
>
> PCENChar ::=
>     "-" | "." | [0-9] | "_" | [a-z] | #xB7 | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x37D] |
>     [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x203F-#x2040] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF]
>     | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> ```

If I'm reading and understanding this correctly, the section of the spec above states that:

- `-` is a valid `PCENChar`

which means that either of the `(PCENChar)*` sequences may contain one or more `-` (... in addition to the obligatory `-` between the two `(PCENChar)*` sequences).

Consequently:

- `<my-custom-element>` *(with two hyphens)*

is a *legitimate* Custom HTML Element name, as are (fairly unexpectedly):

- `<-->`
- `<--->`
- `<---->` etc.

Have I read the spec correctly?

Comment: The last three are not valid, as the name must begin with a letter (the `[a-z]` at the beginning of the `PotentialCustomElementName` production.

Comment: Ohhh. Of course. There's an `[a-z]` at the start. Somehow my brain completely ignored that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: And PCENChar has the Emoji range..So ``<memorize-></memorize->`` is a valid tag name.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - _Oh No You Di'n't!_ Uh... Does that mean `<--‍>` is a valid custom element name (?) Or `<-->` (?)

Comment: No, it needs to start with [a-z]

Comment: Yes. There is a small alphabetic part of my brain which is determined not to boot, today.